What's the benefit to creat an anonymous function and then invoke it immediately?
I read code like this in c++:
const auto candidate_path = std::invoke([&]() {
  if (status == ModuleStatus::SUCCESS || status == ModuleStatus::FAILURE) {
    // clear candidate path if the module is finished
    return convertToPath(nullptr, false, planner_data);
  }
  return convertToPath(
    observer.lock()->getPathCandidate(), observer.lock()->isExecutionReady(), planner_data);
});

The code creates an anonymous function and capture everything by reference [&](){} and then it's called by std::invoke(), I'd like to see if there is any benefit doing it?
Thanks.

This looks like a list type question. List-type question off-topic/unfocussed?

candidate_path can be const

ES.28: Use lambdas for complex initialization, especially of const variables

It truly creates a scope that is connected to the external world by a single return statement. This is mainly to control the initial mutation and auxiliary stuff for the returned object. It is sometimes used to work around deficiencies of the constructors.

The variable candidate_path is intended to be const-qualified. The immediately-invoked lambda allows using (multiple) statements to initialize the variable, rather than just a single expression after the =, without sacrificing const.
In this specific case it would have worked with use of the ternary operator in a single expression as well, but that might be more difficult to read.
The reason to use std::invoke to invoke the lambda instead of writing [&](){ /*...*/ }() is probably personal preference of the author. Possible reason I see is that it is easier to recognize that the lambda is being invoked. With the direct function call syntax one can easily miss the () at the end.

Is lamda function/std::invoke designed to do this, to initialize a const? I have to say c++ is complicated, some side effects are used as common practice (or even common patterns).

@FelixFXu No, lambdas are much more generally useful as a simpler alternative of user-defined classes as function objects when you want to pass "a function" with state to another function. std::invoke's actual purpose is to unify different "invocation" syntax on different kinds of objects, for example to be able to treat member function pointers which need to otherwise be called like obj.*mptr() the same as a function call taking the object as additional first argument: std::invoke(mptr, obj);. This is useful in generic programming with templates.

@FelixFXu I don't know what you mean with side effects, but the pattern used here has the purpose of reducing possible side effects by assuring that there are only const variables. This is essentially something like an improvised functional programming style.

@FelixFXu Lambdas in general are important and everyone writing C++ should know them. The immediately-invoked lambda pattern is not that important and might look confusing at first, but will become natural and obvious once you have seen/used it a few times. std::invoke is not something that C++ users need to know generally. It is only relevant to library authors that need their library functionality to be as generic as possible. It is not needed for the pattern used here and I don't commonly see it used this way.

@FelixFXu Also, if you are still new to C++, the code that you are showing is clearly written by someone with significant experience. It also uses other non-obvious patterns, for example the way the locking is used. Unfortunately C++ is too complicated to be able to get an understanding of code written by an experienced user making use of a lot of its features with just basic understanding of the language. One needs to learn in small steps.
